# Published app now won't run in XCode 7 simulator

Tags: objective-c, xcode7, ios9, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I have an app that has been in the App Store for almost two years.  Published originally for iOS 7, it was updated and runs perfectly under iOS 8, and I just downloaded XCode 7 to make sure I was ready when iOS 9 hits the streets.

I am getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when I run the app in the simulator, but not when I run it on my test device running iOS 9.

I am using NSURLSessionDownloadTask to pull a file down from my server:

```
  NSURLSessionDownloadTask *getTheNoticeFromTheServer = [session downloadTaskWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:completeFilePath]]];
  [getTheNoticeFromTheServer resume];
```

The error hits after I call resume.  Again, this is only when run on the simulator in XCode 7.  Works like a champ on the iOS9 device and on the XCode 6 simulator as well.  Anyone else seen anything like this while using NSURLSession with XCode 7?

Thanks!
Scott

Answer (score 0):

Well I thought XCode 7 Beta 3 fixed this, but it just changed the behavior.  Now the app will run fine on the device by itself, or in the simulator.  But the crash now happens when I run it on the device from within xcode...you know, like you would normally do during development and debugging.  Awesome.